# Create Form and update using same view in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to use same view for creating form and updating any object.

My code is as below, I tried in many ways nothing is working, since I am excluding the shof from form and adding it after form.is_valid() it makes lot of confusion. If I update it creates new object. I have two urls one without ql (create new) and one with ql (update existing), I have a class vdview which provides v.shof which needs to applied in the f.shop in form. please help fix this,

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def addmenu(request, qs, ql=None):
    v = vdview(request, qs)
    ctgobj =  get_object_or_404(v.shopcategs, pk=ql) if ql else None #  ctgobj = ShopCtg(shop=v.shof)
    if ql:
        form = ShopCtgForm(instance=ctgobj) # Tried ShopCtgForm(instance=ctgobj, data=request.POST)
    else:
        form = ShopCtgForm(data= request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            f=form.save(commit=False)
            f.shop = v.shof
            f.save()
            #form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('vendor-shop', qs) #thing='%s added' %f.name)
        else:
            pass
    #else:
    #    form = ShopCtgForm()
    return render(request,'vendorshop.html', {'shop':v.shof, 'shopcategs':v.shopcategs, 'form': form,
    'heading':'Create New Category', 'createcateg': 'createcateg', 'pkaddmenupk':'y'    }    )
```

Comment: What does `ql` stands for? You're getting new instances even with `ql` being not None?

Comment: Are both update and create failing? What is v.shof? Is `f.shop`  `form.shop?` You are forgetting to set data when trying to update the form, it should be `form = ShopCtgForm(instance=ctgobj, data=request.POST)`

Comment: sorry it is now updated. Im going to try with form = ShopCtgForm(instance=ctgobj, data=request.POST). I will post the status.

Comment: Finally this also not working. `
def addmenu(request, qs, ql=None):
    v = vdview(request, qs)
    ctgobj =  get_object_or_404(v.shopcategs, pk=ql) if ql else None
    if ql:
        form = ShopCtgForm(instance=ctgobj, data=request.POST)
        print(ql)
    else:
        form = ShopCtgForm(data= request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            f=form.save(commit=False)
            f.shop = v.shof
            f.save()
            #form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('vendor-shop', qs)
        else:
            pass`

Answer (score 2):

Use `try` blocks to handle both scenarios. The simplified example below will look for a given model instance `pk` and if it doesn't find it, will assume you want to create it.  `try` will prevent django from throwing an error if the model instance doesn't exist.  Rather, it will just return the empty model form.

It does this first to render the correct form in the template (the first `try` block) then again in the second `try` block after `request.method == 'POST':` to submit new data or update existing data.

**Views.py**

```
from .models import Books
from .forms import BookForm

def create_and_update_book_view(request, pk):

    books = Books.objects.get(id=pk)

    try: # get pre-populated form with model instance data (for update)
        form = BookForm(instance=books.id) 
    except: # If it doesn't exist, show an empty form (for create)
        form = BookForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try: # Do the same as above
            form = BookForm(instance=books.id)
        except: # Same as above
            form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, "create_and_update_book_page.html", {'form':form})
```